# New users posts review count calculation

Tags: bug

Suppose if I see a first post asked by a new user, I can use the edit button under the question and make the edits. Something as seen below.

[image]

However, in the review queue, we have an option as First posts which has a gold badge for reviewing 1000 first posts. (As seen here).

[image]

The edits that I do for first posts asked by new users are calculated only from the **review** panel and not if I do from the **edit** under the question. Is it something that can be fixed?

**P.S**: Though this question is childish, the reason is, I just want my user profile to have a flair of golden badges :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the edits performed from the review queues is how these badge tallies get calculated. I along with other's have done many edits and unfortunately these "off book" edits do not count towards any review queue badges. They merely are helping with the maintenance of the site.

It is just how the system works, and I would not consider this a bug, IMO.

**NOTE:** I realize you're kidding with the flair of badges but they are a legitimate motivation, though vain, in getting people to perform various tasks within the site in specific ways, that are conducive to the care and feeding of the site. As one of the few that has almost all the review queue gold badges I understand this drive all too well and would not fault anyone for wanting to attain them 8-).

Just realize that they take a certain amount of discipline to acquire and there is nothing you can do except start watching the review queues like a hawk.

Comment: thanks for clarifying my question. Actually, I am very eager to get lots of badges and reputation and that is the reason for posting this question. Why I included the P.S was some people might feel this question is kiddish :) But not me since I want to be actively involved in this site :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually get the Steward badge for 1000 **Reviews** not for Edits (although that is often a part of the process of reviewing First Posts).

For editing there is a different 'badge track' two of which you already seem to have: "Editor" and "Strunk & White". At 500 total edits (induced through the review queues or by browsing), you can get the "Copy Editor" gold badge. You are almost 2/3 of the way there.

Editing older posts also count against Excavator (which you have) and Archeologist (Silver).

As @slm indicated, watch the queues like a hawk, or alternatively get some help. I had my computer beep at my when review tasks became available, which got me a nice position in most of the queues.